# SIP телефония через pyVOIP, как работать с сервисом: https://bmi.io/en/

Tags: python

Подскажите, какие должны быть минимальные данные, чтобы обеспечить разговор с помощью python, я брал код с github:

```
    from pyVoIP.VoIP import VoIPPhone, InvalidStateError, CallState
    import time
    import wave

    def answer(call):
        try:
            f = wave.open('announcment.wav', 'rb')
            frames = f.getnframes()
            data = f.readframes(frames)
            f.close()
    
            call.answer()
            call.write_audio(data)  # This writes the audio data to the transmit buffer, this must be bytes.

        stop = time.time() + (frames / 8000)  # frames/8000 is the length of the audio in seconds. 8000 is the hertz of PCMU.

        while time.time() <= stop and call.state == CallState.ANSWERED:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        call.hangup()
    except InvalidStateError:
        pass
    except:
        call.hangup()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        phone=VoIPPhone('', callCallback=answer)
        phone.start()
        phone.call('+79043719002')
        input('Press enter to disable the phone')
        phone.stop()
```

Вот какая информация относительно сервиса у меня есть:

Имя устройства ...
Sip пользователь: ...
Sip пароль: ...
Сервер Realm: ...